# How do I recursively check permissions in reverse?

Tags: command-line, shell, permissions

There's a command, I think it comes with apache, or is somehow related to it, that checks permissions, all the way down. So if I have `/home/foo/bar/baz` it will tell me what the permissions are for `baz`, `bar`, `foo`, and `home`. Does anyone know what this command is or another way of doing this? The command basically starts at the argument, and works it's way up to `/` letting you know what the permissions are along the way so you can see if you have a permission problem.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The utility you may be thinking of is the `namei` command.  According to the manual page:

> Namei  uses  its  arguments  as 
>   pathnames to any type of Unix file
>   (symlinks, files, directories, and so
>   forth).  Namei then follows each
>   pathname until a terminal point is
>   found (a file, directory, char device,
>   etc).  If it finds a symbolic link, we
>   show the link, and start following it,
>   indenting the output to show the
>   context.

The output you desire can be received as follows:

```
$ namei -l /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-22/include/
f: /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-22/include/
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root usr
drwxrwsr-x root src  src
drwxr-xr-x root root linux-headers-2.6.35-22
drwxr-xr-x root root include
```

The `namei` command is part of the [linux-util-ng](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux-ng/) software package.  See the  [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/namei.1.html) for more details.

Comment: it might be, seems it only does it for symlinks, though I don't remember what I was using and whether it was on a symlink.

Comment: While I saw older manual pages that only mentioned symlinks, as both my example and the man page show, it words for all types of files and directories.

Comment: not for me :( it long gives a long listing like that, for me, with symlinks.

Comment: what version are you using? I'm using *2.18*

Comment: I'm actually using an older version: 2.17.  What happens when you run it on an easy test case with no symlinks--being sure to pass it the full path name?  Also, does your `man namei` shed any light on this?

Comment: another useful way to use namei for those who are lazy. 
`namei -l $PWD/public_html/`
From your current dir us $PWD to get the list of perms up to your current dir.

Comment: hadn't looked at this in a long time, but I think I just realized why I had problems with it. it looks at the path you give it, so if you do `namei -l file` you'll just get that permission. `namei /home/user/file` would give the listing from root.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not aware of any commands, but it is quite easy to write a script:

```
#!/bin/bash    
ARG=$1
while [[ "$ARG" != "." && "$ARG" != "/" ]]
do
        ls -ld -- "$ARG"
        ARG=`dirname -- "$ARG"`      
done
```

Example:

```
$ perms.sh /tmp/1/2/3/hello.txt

-rw-rw-r--    1 user    group          0 Jan 14 16:59 /tmp/1/2/3/hello.txt
drwxrwxr-x    2 user    group       4096 Jan 14 16:59 /tmp/1/2/3
drwxrwxr-x    3 user    group       4096 Jan 14 16:43 /tmp/1/2
drwxrwxr-x    3 user    group       4096 Jan 14 16:43 /tmp/1
drwxrwxrwt   12 root     root       4096 Jan 14 17:02 /tmp
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the command you where looking for is:

```
namei -l `pwd`
```

which, when executed in /tmp/foo/bar, gives you a listing like:

```
drwxr-xr-x root   root   /
drwxrwxrwt root   root   tmp
drwxr-xr-x user   group  foo
drwxr-xr-x user   group  bar
```

Answer (score 2):

How about a recursive bash function for a fun solution:

```
[bash#] function uptree { ( \ls -ld -- "$PWD"; [ "$PWD" = '/' ] && return; cd ..; uptree ) | column -t ; } 

[bash#] pwd
/home/frielp/bin/dev

[bash#] uptree
drwxrwxr-x.  2   frielp  frielp  4096  Dec  14  14:50  /home/frielp/bin/dev
drwxr-xr-x.  15  frielp  frielp  4096  Aug  23  10:48  /home/frielp/bin
drwxr-xr-x.  60  frielp  frielp  4096  Jan  14  16:48  /home/frielp
drwxr-xr-x.  4   root    root    4096  Dec  1   09:14  /home
dr-xr-xr-x.  23  root    root    4096  Jan  14  08:18  /

[bash#] pwd
/home/frielp/bin/dev
[bash#]
```

Comment: This is my favorite because it requires no dependencies. Might want to make it `cd .. >/dev/null` though for those of us with a `$CDPATH` set (which causes cd to output the current dir when it's used and that interferes with the output from your function.)

Answer (score 1):

This could easily be made a one-liner. This is not recursive and should be a relatively fast way of doing this in bash. Calling *pwd* in each loop isn't particularly fast, so avoid if you can.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 [FILE]"
    exit 1
fi
cd -P -- "$1"
IFS="/"
set -f # turn off globbing for the expansion of $PWD below
for dir in $PWD; do
    stat -c "$PWD %A" .
    cd ..
done
```

---

Alternative, a one-liner for the current directory.

```
(IFS="/"; set -f; for dir in $PWD; do stat -c "$PWD %A" .; cd ..; done)
```

Comment: Is that a one-liner? Did I miss something?

Comment: As a one-liner for the pwd: pushd $(pwd) >/dev/null; OIFS=$IFS; IFS="/"; for dir in $(pwd); do stat -c "$(pwd) %A" .; cd ..; done; IFS=$OIFS; popd >/dev/null

Comment: Your script won't work with file names containing spaces or globbing characters.

Comment: Gilles, I guess not. It had originally, but I mucked it up in editing. I've removed the xargs and it should work properly again.

Comment: Why use pushd and popd? Or eval, for that matter? You can use a subshell (parentheses) to keep all changes local. You need double quotes to protect directory names with spaces, and `set -f` to turn off globbing. `cd -P` follows all symlinks.

Answer (score 1):

alternately, consider using `find` with `tac`

```
find /path -printf '%M %u %g %p\n' | tac
```