# Figuring out why permission is denied on a file by recursively checking permission on parents

Tags: permissions, directory-structure

I get permission denied on a file `/some/very/long/path` while trying to do `df` on it.

I try to do `df /some/very/long` and get the same. Then I go one more level up `df /some/very`, still same.

Finally, when doing `df /some` I see the reason - I am not part of the group that owns `/some` (so I can't see anything under it).

Is there a one liner command that can tell me the above? Without me having to write a script to traverse up the hierarchy to figure it out?

Comment: Relating: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5860

Comment: `namei` only works if I have permission on the path to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a `bash` script to address this problem, see [it on github](https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld)

Comment: Thanks. I have a python script to do this myself as well. But I was hoping to find a command or a one liner. But thanks anyway.